# Navigating along diagonal fence

Tags: matrix, navigation, 2d, game-physics

I am writing an MMORPG game and I'm having trouble with player movement on the server.  I have a 2D matrix of 0.5 x 0.5 meter cells to act as the passibility map for players.  The problem I'm having is depicted below.  If a player is moving along (and very close to) a diagonal wall or fence, he is getting blocked by the very geometry of the blocky map.  This doesn't happen if fences/walls are aligned with the world (vertically or horizontally).  The obvious solution is to increase the player radius so he can't get that close to the fence, or possibly make the cells smaller (which would really accomplish the same thing).  But, can anyone think of an alternate method?
I can't simply say "hey, this is diagonal so I'll draw an imaginary line from corner to corner and make sure the player can't cross that line". This won't work because, as you can see below, a fence run can have some horizontal or vertical repetitions here and there.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

[image: Moving along diagonal fence or wall]

Comment: Something interesting I noticed is that this blocking isn't much of a problem if I walk along the fence with the fence to my right.  So I can keep walking around a long diagonal fence segment clockwise without much of a problem.  If I try it counter-clockwise (fence on my left), I'll get stuck almost immediately.  I'm confused because this proves that it doesn't have anything to do with whether X is increasing or decreasing or if Y is increasing or decreasing.  What matters is which side of the fence I'm on.

Answer (score 0):

Where is everyone?
I solved this on my own just now by doing the following.

If a character's move is blocked, the server will first try:

If delta X is not already 0, try the same move with 0 for delta X.

If that's blocked, put delta X back and try with delta Y as 0 and try again.

If that's blocked too, the move is blocked.

This will allow sliding along a diagonal fence.  If the fence is X or Y aligned, obviously this component method doesn't come into play but it's not needed in that case because the geometry won't block you.
I haven't yet checked what it looks like to another observer (another character logged in).  It could look very jagged and jumpy to another player when it keeps zeroing his X or Y movement as he brushes up against a fence or wall.  This works for now though!